# Guitar Chord Detection?

Tags: algorithm, fft, detection, guitar, music-notation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guitar Chord Recognition Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033083/guitar-chord-recognition-algorithm)

Hi!

Im trying to find algorithms and ways on how to detect Guitar Chords, specifically by trying to identify which notes comprise the chord.

For now, one of the possible ways I see this is to use the FFT bins. I understand that the bins have certain intensities associated with them so I wonder if the notes that comprise the chord will have high intensity compared to others. A

Comment: Search Stack Overflow for "chord", "pitch", "FFT", "cepstrum", "autocorrelation", etc - it seems that many people want to write guitar tuners etc for various devices and the algorithms and techniques have been covered at length in previous questions.